# Opening different tabs of same workbook in different windows in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, is there a way to open different tabs of the same workbook in separate windows?  It's possible to open different workbooks in separate windows by opening multiple instances of Excel but that isn't working for opening different tabs of the same workbook since an error message arises that the workbook is already locked for editing.

Answer (score 23):

There is a "New Window" button on the View tab of the Ribbon.

If you follow this up by clicking "Arrange All" you can view the same worksheet in two different places (side by side or stacked).

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Thanks @devuxer - this works great for opening separate sheets of the same workbook on different monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I did View | Arrange All | and then selected "Windows of the active workbook". Since I only had two active worksheets this let me see both tabs. At first it shows the same tab in both windows. Just select the other tab you want to view in one window and "boom' you can see and switch between both.